# pass an object via array index from data to a component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

My parent app has the following data structure

```
export default {
      name: "app",
      components: {
        Template1
      },
      data() {
          appState: {
            questionCount: 0,
            isIntro: true, //when true, perform single initial animation
          },
          questions: [
            {
              id: 0,
              question: "What do you think is most helpful in increasing workforce diversity?",
            }
            ...
          ]
      }
    }
```

I want to render Template1 with just the question object from the data equal to the current question count, so I tried this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Template1
      questionItem="questions[appState.questionCount]"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

But I don't think that is the proper way to reference an array index. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind it using `v-bind:` or just `:` as follows :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Template1
      :questionItem="questions[appState.questionCount]"
    />
  </div>
</template
```